# Vector in linear span

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have to check if a vector $\textbf w$ is in a linear span of some vectors $\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2,\textbf v_3$, so that $\textbf w \in span(\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2,\textbf v_3)$, can I form a matrix with $[\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2,\textbf v_3]$, calculate the rank, then add $\textbf w$ to the matrix, and then caluculate the new rank of $[\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2,\textbf v_3,\textbf w]$, and if the rank doesn't change then : $\textbf w$ lies in $span(\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2,\textbf v_3)$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can prove it to yourself as an exercise

Comment: This will work, but there’s no need to do two computations. If the last column of the rref of $[\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\mathbf v_3,\mathbf w]$ doesn’t have a pivot, then $\mathbf w$ lies in the span of the other vectors.

Comment: Ok, many thanks !!